# Firefox improperly renders linear and radial gradients

Tags: css, firefox, rendering, linear-gradients, radial-gradients

I'm trying to use the gradient property to create a background and for some reason, it renders gradients wrong in firefox but perfectly in chrome based browsers. I've tried using -moz- and it doesn't help. For some reason, it creates a bunch of distinct lines and it looks really bad when I try to make it bigger.

```
body {
height: 100vh;
width: 100vh;
background-image: radial-gradient(hwb(0 35% 65%) -100%,  hwb(0 13% 87%));
background-size: 200% 200%;
background-position: bottom;
}
```

Check out these pictures for reference
[Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVGt6.png)
[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TFfZ.png)

Comment: I don't see any difference

Comment: @Rob I changed it up a bit. hopefully you can see the lines I'm taking about. They are a lot more obvious on larger screen sizes so you might need to zoom in.

Comment: It's called [banding](https://www.willgibbons.com/color-banding/). In Firefox, it's a known bug apparently, and there's no fix yet. See [bug #627771](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=627771).